# How would I get rid of the old class name in my console whenever I run my code?

Tags: java, eclipse

At first, my class name was called `App.java`, but now I decided to rename it as `Main.java`.  However, whenever I run my code, on the top of the console, I'm still getting `App [Java Application]`.

How do I make it so that it says `Main [Java Application]`?

[image]

Comment: Click the down-arrow next to the Run button, choose "Run Configurations...", then change the name of your run configuration for this application .

Comment: @Berger Thanks a lot, worked like a charm.

Comment: Added it as an answer, since I couldn't find many clear things about it when searching.

Answer (score 0):

Click the down-arrow next to the Run button :

[image]

Choose "Run Configurations...", then change the name of your run configuration for this application :

[image]